# Accessing MS Outlooks Distribution lists

Tags: outlook, ms-office

We want to develope a special e-mail tool. One of its main features should be the ability to send mails to useres and distributions lists which are saved at Outlook.

To make it short: Is there a possibility to access the distribuiton lists of Outlook from an external tool without gaining high security risks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a possibility to access the distribuiton lists of Outlook from an external tool without gaining high security risks?

Yes, there is. See [How to automate Outlook from another program](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/201096?wa=wsignin1.0).

Also you may find the [Outlook "Object Model Guard" Security Issues for Developers](http://www.outlookcode.com/article.aspx?id=52) page helpful.

Comment: can you tell me which Outlook version the microsoft thread is reffering to?

Comment: The information is valid for Outlook 2000 and later.